# Creating login and logout class based views in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am learning class based views in Django 1.8, and wondering if anyone could help me here. I have created a function based login and logout views as you can see below:

**LOGIN**

```
def Login(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/form')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Inactive user.")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

    return render(request, "index.html")
```

**LOGOUT**

```
def Logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Could anyone help me to convert these views into `Class Based Views` in Django? I am pretty new to this stuff, and couldn't understand properly how exactly they are working. Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go through the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views

```
from django.views.generic import View

class LoginView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/form')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Inactive user.")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

        return render(request, "index.html")

class LogoutView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```